# try to convert a function to a more functional style

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, refactoring

I'm learning functional programming and I will like to know what would be the best approach to refactor the bellow function, to see best practices

I'm refactoring a Object Oriented Particle System that I made, so here first is the code that I made as a class:

```
submitToFields(fields) {
    let totalAccelerationX = 0;
    let totalAccelerationY = 0;
    fields.forEach(field => {
      const vectorX = field.position.x - this.position.x;
      const vectorY = field.position.y - this.position.y;
      const force = Particle.calculateForce(field, vectorX, vectorY);
      totalAccelerationX += vectorX * force;
      totalAccelerationY += vectorY * force;
    });
    this.acceleration = new Vector(totalAccelerationX, totalAccelerationY);
  }
```

- This method belongs to a particle object that has position, velocity, acceleration,etc
- fiels is an array of field objects with an structure like {position: {x:0,y:0}, mass:140, ...}
- vector is an object like {x:0,y:0}
- The method calculates the disturbance acceleration that the particle is affected by fields (gravitational mass) on the particle system

Ok now this is what I got so far but I will like to drill a little bit more about functional and try to be more point free and other goodies that functional programming can offer me.

```
const add = a => b => a + b;
const propX = R.prop('x');
const propY = R.prop('y');
const addVectors = (vectorA, vectorB) =>
  vector(
    add(propX(vectorA))(propX(vectorB)),
    add(propY(vectorA))(propY(vectorB)),
  );
const vector = (a, b) => ({ x: a, y: b });
const square = x => x ** 2;
const difference = a => b => a - b;
const position = item => R.prop('position', item) || 0;
const posX = item => R.prop('x', position(item)) || 0;
const posY = item => R.prop('y', position(item)) || 0;
const propMass = item => R.prop('mass', item) || 0;

const calculateForce = (mass, vectr) => {
  return mass / (square(vectr.x) + square(vectr.y) + mass) ** 1.5;
};


const disturbanceAcceleration = (part, fields) => {
  const partX = posX(part);
  const partY = posY(part);
  return fields.reduce((acc, curr) => {
    const fieldX = difference(posX(curr))(partX);
    const fieldY = difference(posY(curr))(partY);
    const force = calculateForce(propMass(curr), vector(fieldX, fieldY));
    const newVector = vector(fieldX * force, fieldY * force);
    return addVectors(acc, newVector);
  }, vector(0, 0));
};
```

Here is a test:

Given:

```
const part = {position:{x:0,y:0}};

const fields = [
 {position:{x:100,y:100}, mass:140},
 {position:{x:200,y:100}, mass:140} , 
 {position:{x:150,y:300}, mass:140}];
```

execute:

```
disturbanceAcceleration(part,fields)
```

Output:

```
{x: 0.007947635786319896, y: 0.007256173830876778}
```

Comment: Sure, you can create a complex composition within `disturbanceAcceleration` to avoid intermediate values. But this won't give you much. At a certain level of complexity intermediate results are just helpful to keep track of the data flow and to understand the algorithm.

Comment: You can generalize `position` by passing a default value `positionOr = def => ...`. This way you are also more explicit about the circumstance, that there may not be a position at all.

Comment: "*try to be more point free*" - that's often pointless. Use it when it's applicable, but don't force it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Vector.js**

Starting with a basic `Vector` module, we use objects to hold `x` and `y` properties, but we make sure Vector operations `add`, `difference`, and `scale` do not *mutate* the object; instead, a new Vector is always returned -

```
const Vector = (x = 0, y = 0) =>
  ({ x, y })

Vector.add = (a = Vector (), b = Vector ()) =>
  Vector
    ( a.x + b.x
    , a.y + b.y
    )

Vector.difference = (a = Vector (), b = Vector ()) =>
  Vector
    ( a.x - b.x
    , a.y - b.y
    )

Vector.scale = ({ x, y } = Vector (), k = 1) =>
  Vector
    ( x * k
    , y * k
    )

// ...

export default Vector
```

**Field.js**

Then we build a `Field` module, which depends on `Vector`. Again, we ensure that we do not use mutable operations -

```
const Vector =
  require ('./Vector')

const Field = (mass = 0, position = Vector ()) =>
  ({ mass, position })

Field.calculateForce = ({ mass, position:{ x, y } } = Field ()) =>
  mass / (x ** 2 + y ** 2 + mass) ** 1.5

Field.disturbanceAcceleration = (origin, fields = []) =>
  fields.reduce
    ( (acc, { mass, position }) =>
      { const v =
          Vector.difference (position, origin)

        const force =
          Field.calculateForce (Field (mass, v))

        return Vector.add
          ( acc
          , Vector.scale (v, force)
          )
      }
    , Vector ()
    )

// ...

export default Field
```

Now for our solution -

```
import Vector from './Vector'
import Field from './Field'

const fields =
  [ Field (140, Vector (100, 100))
  , Field (140, Vector (200, 100))
  , Field (140, Vector (150, 300))
  ]

Field.disturbanceAcceleration (Vector (), fields)
// { x: 0.007947635786319896, y: 0.007256173830876778 }
```

The use of default arguments affords us extremely convenient use of our data types. These are things we don't take for granted -

```
Vector ()         // { x: 0, y: 0 }
Vector () .x      // 0
Vector () .y      // 0
Vector (1, 2) .x  // 1
Vector (1, 2) .y  // 2

Field ()                                 // { mass: 0, position: { x: 0, y: 0 } }
Field () .mass                           // 0
Field () .position                       // { x: 0, y: 0 }
Field (100) .mass                        // 100
Field (100) .position                    // { x: 0, y: 0 }
Field (100, Vector (1, 2)) .mass         // 100
Field (100, Vector (1, 2)) .position .x  // 1
Field (100, Vector (1, 2)) .position .y  // 2
```

**myparticle.js**

Your may end up with many sub-modules, and that's ok. It's likely you will want to combine the sub-modules into a single greater module, perhaps one we name  *myparticle* -

```
import Vector from './Vector'
import Field from './Field'
// ...

export { Vector, Field /*, ... */ }
```

Then when we use it in our solution -

```
import { Vector, Field /*, ... */ } from ('myparticle')

// ...
```

---

**Code demo**

Expand the snippet below to verify the results in your own browser -

```js
// Vector -------------------------------------------
const Vector = (x = 0, y = 0) =>
  ({ x, y })

Vector.add = (a = Vector (), b = Vector ()) =>
  Vector
    ( a.x + b.x
    , a.y + b.y
    )

Vector.difference = (a = Vector (), b = Vector ()) =>
  Vector
    ( a.x - b.x
    , a.y - b.y
    )

Vector.scale = ({ x, y } = Vector (), k = 1) =>
  Vector
    ( x * k
    , y * k
    )

// Field -------------------------------------------
const Field = (mass = 0, position = Vector ()) =>
  ({ mass, position })

Field.calculateForce = ({ mass, position:{ x, y } } = Field ()) =>
  mass / (x ** 2 + y ** 2 + mass) ** 1.5

Field.disturbanceAcceleration = (origin, fields = []) =>
  fields.reduce
    ( (acc, { mass, position }) =>
      { const v =
          Vector.difference (position, origin)

        const force =
          Field.calculateForce (Field (mass, v))
            
        return Vector.add
          ( acc
          , Vector.scale (v, force)
          )
      }
    , Vector ()
    )

// Demo -------------------------------------------
const fields =
  [ Field (140, Vector (100, 100))
  , Field (140, Vector (200, 100))
  , Field (140, Vector (150, 300))
  ]

const result =
  Field.disturbanceAcceleration (Vector (), fields)
  
console .log (result)
// { x: 0.007947635786319896, y: 0.007256173830876778 }
```

---

**Plain object modules**

Above we made a *function* `Vector` an then attach `add`, `difference`, and `scale` as properties of the function. This works in JavaScript because functions are objects and we can assign properties in any way we choose. This design allows us to construct vectors using `Vector` as a constructor function, and then calling `Vector.add`, `Vector.scale`, etc for our vector-related operations.

Another design would be to make `Vector` a *plain object*. Vector operations `add`, `difference`, and `scale` can be added as properties of the object. Then the constructor can be added as a property, `make`, or any name of your choosing -

```
// Vector.js
const make = (x = 0, y = 0) =>
  ({ x, y })

const add = ...

const difference = ...

const scale = ...

export { make, add, difference, scale }
```

`Vector` is no longer a function. Instead, the constructor is exported as `make`. Now we construct vectors using `Vector.make` -

```
import Vector from './Vector'

const u =
  Vector.make (1, 1) // must call Vector.make

const v =
  Vector.make (2, 3) // must call Vector.make

Vector.add (u, v)    // { x: 3, y: 4 }
```

Whatever way you decide to package your modules is up to you, just make sure it's consistent.

Comment: I don't know about particle systems so if I accidentally grouped `calculateForce` or `disturbanceAcceleration` with the wrong module, you'll have to correct that. Also note we didn't reach for a third-party library before needing it. Ensure you understand what you are gaining before electing potentially complex dependencies.

Comment: thanks !!
I had my code split on modules but for simplicity on this code I grabb and putt them all together.

I have one last concern,looking at your code I see that you are adding new methods attached to Fields and Vectors, so I thought maybe it's a good idea to extend from prototype instead of adding them to the constant (I guess this is because of my OO point of view) , but then I realize that we are not instantiate any object , we are just executing a function and then returning a new object that do not have any other property attach to it , is my assumption right?

Comment: Correct, we are not instantiating objects. Functions are objects in JavaScript, so we can attach `add`, `difference`, and `scale` as properties of the `Vector` function. In OO terms, you can think of this as a class method.

Comment: @Boogie I provided additional explanation at the bottom of the answer. Lmk if you have any other questions :D